# Problem in creating an alarm in Typescript but the alarm isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, clock

I am creating an alarm clock using typescript and I am facing in issue. I am not being alarmed when the time passes.
I have taken three inputs from the HTML page – **Hours**, **Minutes** and **Seconds**.

After that I added them and subtracted the current time.

```
    let h = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("h");//getting input values of hour and ...
    let m = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("m");
    let s = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("s");

    let h1 = parseFloat(h.value);//converting the input values from string to float
    let m1 = parseFloat(m.value);
    let s1 = parseFloat(s.value);

    var rHours = new Date().getHours();
    var rMinutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    var rSeconds = new Date().getMinutes();
    var calc = (h1) + (m1) + (s1) - rHours - rMinutes - rSeconds;
    
    if(calc<=0){
       alert("Alarm");
    }
}
```

But it does not work properly.

Comment: this is confusing the way you're calculating but i don't see a countdown. Can you post the rest of this code so we can see the actual countdown part?

Comment: @Kinglish I have edited the question so that it is more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've haven't built a countdown timer in a while, so I thought I'ddo it for fun. This isn't especially Typescript, but it does run just fine in the compiler (see link below). It's regular JS so it will run in the snippet as well. I thought it might help you see how a countdown timer would work. Your code didn't reflect any kind of countdown, and your method of determining elapsed time was incorrect.

For the purposes of the demo, I set `h1`, `m1` and `s1` to dynamically be 1 minute from whenever the snippet is run. You can easily adapt this to work from your input elements.

```js
document.querySelector('p span').innerHTML = new Date().toString()

function startCountdown() {
/* In your code uncomment this section...
    let el_h = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("h");
    let el_m = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("m");
    let el_s = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("s");
*/

  // in your code comment out these lines and use yours from above instead (for typescript typing)
  let el_h = document.getElementById("h");
  let el_m = document.getElementById("m");
  let el_s = document.getElementById("s");


  let h1 = parseFloat(el_h.value);
  let m1 = parseFloat(el_m.value);
  let s1 = parseFloat(el_s.value);


  //const [h1, m1, s1] = ( (new Date().getHours() ) + ":" + (new Date().getMinutes() + 2) + ":" + new Date().getSeconds()).split(":");

  // get todays date
  let today = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + "-" + new Date().getDate();

  // add on the hours from the inputs
  today += " " + h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + s1;
  const myTime = new Date(today);

  console.log('countdown to:', myTime, 'from:', new Date());
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let diff = (myTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000; // seconds
    let h = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
    let m = Math.floor(diff / 60 % 60);
    let s = Math.floor(diff % 60)
    console.log(h + " hours, " + m + " minutes, " + s + " seconds")
    if (diff <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("ALARM");
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<p>Cur time: <span></span></p>
<input id='h' placeholder='Hour (military time)'><input id='m' placeholder='Minute'><input id='s' placeholder='Seconds'><button onclick='startCountdown()'>Start</button>
```

[tsplayground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA2gCwIwBoYFtUwkgujAXhgAoSwBTAdxgBEBDKc4gSgDoBzcqACRAFcAThBYxmMANQwARAC4pEslVoMmbTlACyASzB9GwsZIBMh6XIUVq9Riw5cAyuVBgAJgbYQADgBstUYrJSzADcAFChMJEwAPTRMOowUCAudACeEDApjBFR3lyJyWmEMJbKNmpcAGJ83t4AmuR0AiKSUgC08pLEpdaqdprgUAgtMEim7Z0lSr226jMh4VExcXQuLjDgiQjkMAj8QjAAZgIg6Fs7Op56EDmRSSmpEkTyk8gKgQqY7%20aSOGFLzmgGFSABUtOgdkQeipiPc0gtbjBASA8qxvCB2MQAOSgPhgKAuECUMAFGRYtDoUHg8hoLHHU5ktDQ8oLAHgIE6RgCABudG8xQgXAAkvjyDy%20cQRAQAHwwADeiMieVgLi0h0OxWIlLBEP6OtUMDaUysMIqUH1LDEcSQAAY7cFltgnOA3IqYMrdsUNAwEKxDuiQM1VerogBmABsdtZS2WyNR6MxwcOKAQzDdHrORG9Qz9AaDasO0UjAFJI9Glh6MlmfbmQIHiEnSza0zGkeyUeQ0RjiAhxPI9oIIGgpOJ0H2MDo9OQh9JxBBx4LnG4gm61SQkzAADxEZvyt2RYB5Joirm87zETlis-lmNxzsJgIAQQAMo%20AEoaIL-GMAX0RP7QW0oyAA)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I will try it out.
Can you tell me the use of clearInterval?

Comment: Also, you have predefined the countdown to be 2 minutes. But, I want the user to input a time and then get an alarm when the time is crossed.

Comment: @NisargKudgunti- setInterval makes the countdown run every second (it takes time in miliseconds, and I set it to 1000) - it will run forever unless we use  clearInterval(intverval) to stop it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: using the little snippet button in the SO toolbar

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('p span').innerHTML = new Date().toString()

function startCountdown() {
/* In your code uncomment this section...
    let el_h = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("h");
    let el_m = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("m");
    let el_s = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("s");
*/

  // in your code comment out these lines and use yours from above instead (for typescript typing)
  let el_h = document.getElementById("h");
  let el_m = document.getElementById("m");
  let el_s = document.getElementById("s");


  let h1 = parseFloat(el_h.value);
  let m1 = parseFloat(el_m.value);
  let s1 = parseFloat(el_s.value);


  //const [h1, m1, s1] = ( (new Date().getHours() ) + ":" + (new Date().getMinutes() + 2) + ":" + new Date().getSeconds()).split(":");

  // get todays date
  let today = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + "-" + new Date().getDate();

  // add on the hours from the inputs
  today += " " + h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + s1;
  const myTime = new Date(today);

  console.log('countdown to:', myTime, 'from:', new Date());
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let diff = (myTime.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000; // seconds
    let h = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
    let m = Math.floor(diff / 60 % 60);
    let s = Math.floor(diff % 60)
    console.log(h + " hours, " + m + " minutes, " + s + " seconds")
    if (diff <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("ALARM");
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<p>Cur time: <span></span></p>
<input id='h' placeholder='Hour (military time)'><input id='m' placeholder='Minute'><input id='s' placeholder='Seconds'><button onclick='startCountdown()'>Start</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).